# Tensorflow C++ simple graph creation example execution

Tags: c++

I want to see the output of `/tensorflow/cc/example_trainer.cc` file,
for that I build the code using `bazel run :example_trainer.cc` and it was successfully build.
But I didn't see and output

```
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/cc/example:example.cc (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.236s, Critical Path: 0.03s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

Comment: Please post the full command line you are executing.

Comment: Please share your code also. you have shared only output of your code